# How does Tomcat know what Host to use for a given request

Tags: tomcat

I have a Tomcat with two `<Host>` entries inside one `<Engine>`, say

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="www.foo.com">
    <Host name="www.foo.com"  appBase="fooapps"/>
    <Host name="www.bar.com"  appBase="barapps"/>
</Engine>
```

This doesn't work -- all requests are routed to the default host -- and I'm wondering why.
The tomcat documentation says

> Tomcat extracts the host name **from the HTTP headers** and looks for a
> Host with a matching name. If no match is found, the request is routed
> to the default host.

What is (are) the actual header(s) that Tomcat looks at to decide what `Host` a particular request is for?

--- edit ---

I was able to solve the root problem. There was an Apache httpd server in front of the Tomcat that I was unaware of. Adding `ProxyPreserveHost On` made the proper pages show up for each domain.

However out of curiosity I would still like to know what the headers are that Tomcat uses to figure this out.

Comment: Which host do you use to access the site?

Comment: Requests from both hosts (ren and stimpy in the example) basically show the pages from the defaultHost (ren in the example). I would expect requests from stimpy to show the pages from stimpyapps.

Comment: Host names are domain names. These aren’t.

Comment: @user207421 In reality the names used in the server config do match the actual domain names, including the necessary Aliases. I updated the question to reflect this, by using more realistic domain names.

Comment: The HTTP request header that contains the hostname that Tomcat maps to a Host scope is, wait for it, [the Host header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4), which was standardized by HTTP/1.1 in 1997 but widely used before that as an extension to 1.0. No browser supported now or in the past decade ever sends a request without Host, but ancient defective proxies may, as may some applications using very obsolete code.

Comment: @user207421+ a domain-name _can_ be a single label, and moreover a URI authority host need not even be a domain-name much less a FQDN or actually in DNS, see 3986 3.2.2, although for a public-use server on the public Internet -- what 3986 calls a 'global scope' URI -- FQDN in DNS is pretty much the only practical choice. That doesn't mean it's the case in this Q.

Comment: solved the root issue - see edit above. However this still doesn't answer the original question i.e. what headers are involved in this?

Comment: It's exactly what @dave_thompson_085 has commented. And now that you've fixed your reverse proxy, Tomcat actually sees that header. Alternatively, X-Forwarded-For (or similar)

Comment: Yes 'PreserveHost' retains the Host header sent/requested by the client. @OlafKock: X-Forwarded-Host also does this, but X-Forwarded-For provides (to the backend) the address of the original (real) _client_ which is quite different.

Comment: Oops, indeed. The intuition to add "or similar" seems to have sneaked into my mind for a good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only header Tomcat looks at for this is the Host header.